# Daily Balance report

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

I have to make daily report from an SQL table which contains ID (user id), Timestamp, Balance Transactions.

My quest: Every transactions have been stored in the table. I have to know the summary all user's balance on every day.

For examle:

```
27/06/2016 8:10 User1 50$

27/06/2016 10:22 User1 75$

27/06/2016 11:32 User2 10$

28/06/2016 09:22 User3 40$

28/06/2016 17:35 User1 22$
```

In this case the results have to be the following:

`27/06/2016: 85$` (75+10) because last user1's balance 75 and user2 10

`28/06/2016: 72$` (22+10+40) because last user1's balance 22 and user2 10 (it was modified on yesterday but I have to count it!!!) and user3 22$

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: As @EvaldasBuinauskas said what have you tried so far? Hint group by date and use SUM()

Comment: CTE creating the table for me contains a lot of joins


CTE2 (id,currentbalance,,dt) as
(
select * from cte where dt in  (select   MAX(dt)
    FROM     cte
    GROUP BY id,DAY(dt), MONTH(dt), YEAR(dt))
)
select cast(dt as date) as stat_day,sum(currentbalance) as currentbalance from CTE2
GROUP BY cast(dt as date)
order by stat_day


But it is not good because if a account was not modified on this day, then it is not counting :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new solution...

Identify the last balance per user per day and sum them up by day:

```
with CTE as
(
select t.*, 
       row_number() 
         over(partition by user, cast(t_date as date) order by t_date desc) as rn
from transactions t
)
select cast(t_date as date) as t_date, sum(amount) as total_amount
from CTE
where rn = 1
group by cast(t_date as date)
```

Comment: Almost good but not....
If only one account modified it on 28/06/2016 it does not add other balances for the summary. For example:

user3 balance: 75$ on 28/06/2016 but user2 was modified on 01/06/2016 then user2 not added to the balance of 28/06/2016